# UUID cannot be resolved error

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

Here again....

I´m trying to create a Bluetooth connection, I already have the MAC address of the device but when I use createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord it gives me an error on the UUID... does anyone haves a clue on why is this?.... I appreciate in advance the help.

Here's the Main:

```
package com.example.mustangsound;



//import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Set;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String toastText = "";
    private BluetoothDevice btDevice;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
    private String btAddress = "11:22:33:44:44:44";
    String mArrayAdapter = "";
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void BTConnect (View v){

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        else{

            toastText="Connecting to Mustang Sound Bluetooth receiver.... please wait";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btAddress);
            btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("0000111F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
            btSocket.connect();

        }

    }



    public void LightsOn (View v){

        toastText="Sounds Lights On";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void LightsOff (View v){

        toastText="Sounds Lights Off";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void DoorsOpen (View v){

        toastText="Opening Sound doors";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void DoorsClose (View v){

        toastText="Closing Sound doors";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void SysOn (View v){

        toastText="IT'S ALIVE!!!!!.....IT'S ALIIIIIVEEEEEE";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void SysOff (View v){

        toastText="Mustnag Sound OFF";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



}
```

Comment: what error does it give you? can you provide a stack trace + error.

Comment: Is it because you commented out the `import java.util.UUID` ?

Comment: This is the error that gives me at the time of compilation: UUID cannot be resolved... and if I enable the UUID utility it gives me the following errors on btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("c50c4690-8bbe-11e3-baa8-0800200c9a66")); and btSocket.connect();....: Unhandled exception type IOExeption

Comment: In what environment are you debugging this? on hardware? emulator?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that AndroidStudio/IntelliJ has a bug somewhere so java util jar is not added to compile classpath. Ironically - autocomplete works when typing `import` statement. Strange enough, in your case - for `java.util.Set` it worked out. `Set` might have been available elsewhere, while I've had the same issue for `java.util.Date`.

To me that happened on a brand new project, but the solution was to quit AndroidStudio, remove `.iml` file and `.idea` dir and reopen the project. After re-sync from gradle - all's good.

Comment: Adding `import java.util.*` manually in IntelliJ IDEA solved this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after restarted IntelliJ, the issue was resolved. This is for the 2022 IntelliJ version.